# I'm getting weird results from this code in c

Tags: c

I am new to coding, and I am starting with creating functions. I am having trouble with a project, and when making few test with the code, I get weird results. The code is functions/actions to get a user from the input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

/*CONSTANT DEFINITION - Instead of using define, using const for making it more readable*/

#define MAX_NAME_LEN  25
const int NUM_SUPPORTERS = 3;
const int BASE_MEMBERSHIP_YEARS = 5;
const int SILVER_MEMBERSHIP_YEARS = 10;
const int BASE_MEMBERSHIP_POINTS = 10;
const int SILVER_MEMBERSHIP_POINTS = 15;
const int GOLD_MEMBERSHIP_POINTS = 20;
const int RECORDS_PENALTY_POINTS = 5;


    
/*DECLARATION OF STRUCT FOR TSUPPORTER*/
    typedef struct {
        char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
        int age;
        int membershipYears;
        int hasRecords;
        int membershipCategory;
    } tSupporter;

/*PREDECLARACION*/

void getMembershipType(int membershipYears, int *memberShipType);
void readSupporter(tSupporter *aficionado);
void writeSupporter (tSupporter users, int memberShipType);
void getPoints(tSupporter aficionado, int memberShipType, int hasRecords, int *totalPointsSupporter, int i);
void supporterCpy(tSupporter users[], tSupporter aficionado, int i);


/*   2.5 ALGORITHM  */

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    printf ("INPUT DATA\n");
    /*VAR DECLARATION*/
    tSupporter aficionado;
    int totalPointsSupporter[NUM_SUPPORTERS];
    tSupporter users[NUM_SUPPORTERS];
    int i, n, m;
    int memberShipType;
    
    for (n=0; n<NUM_SUPPORTERS; n++){
        
        /*Reading the supporter data*/
        readSupporter(&aficionado);
        i = n; 
        /*Copy the supporter data to tSuppoter Array where NUM_SUPPORTER EQUALS TO i*/
        supporterCpy(users, aficionado, i);
        /*Getting the type of membership and copy to new struct*/
        getMembershipType(aficionado.membershipYears, &memberShipType);
        users[i].membershipCategory = memberShipType;
        /*getting the points for the user in the array*/
        getPoints(aficionado, memberShipType, aficionado.hasRecords, &totalPointsSupporter[i], i);
                
    }
    
    /*NO TIE*/ 
    /*Calculating and printing higher position based only on points*/
    if (totalPointsSupporter[0] != totalPointsSupporter[1] && totalPointsSupporter[1] != totalPointsSupporter[2] && totalPointsSupporter[0] != totalPointsSupporter[2]){
        int aPosition = 0;
        int a = totalPointsSupporter[0];

        /*FInd the highest supporter points*/
        for (int t = 0; t < NUM_SUPPORTERS; t++) {
            if (totalPointsSupporter[t] > a) {
                a = totalPointsSupporter[t];
                aPosition = t;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
    
    printf("SELECTED SUPPORTER:\n");
    writeSupporter(users[aPosition], memberShipType);
    printf("POINTS: %d\n", totalPointsSupporter[aPosition]); 
     
        }

    }   

    /*IF THERE IS TIE*/
    
    /*If there is tie check for the user with higher membership time*/
    if (totalPointsSupporter [0] == totalPointsSupporter [1] || totalPointsSupporter [1] == totalPointsSupporter [2] || totalPointsSupporter [2] == totalPointsSupporter [0]){
                
            int aTheWinnerIs = users[0].membershipYears;
            int aTheWinnerIsIndex = 0;

            for (m = 0; m < NUM_SUPPORTERS; m++) {
                if (users[m].membershipYears > aTheWinnerIs) {
                    aTheWinnerIs = users[m].membershipYears;
                    aTheWinnerIsIndex = m;
                }
            }
            
        /*PRINT WINNER*/
            printf("SELECTED SUPPORTER\n");
            writeSupporter(users[aTheWinnerIs], users[aTheWinnerIsIndex].membershipYears);
            printf("POINTS: %d\n", totalPointsSupporter[aTheWinnerIsIndex]);
        
        
            } else { /*If there is tie check for the user with higher membership time and same time of membership, choose the first one choosen*/
            
                    printf("SELECTED SUPPORTER:\n");
                    writeSupporter(users[0], users[0].membershipYears);
                    printf("POINTS: %d\n", totalPointsSupporter[0]);
            }    

            
    return 0;
}
    
    
/*FUNCTIONS AND ACTIONS*/ 

/*2.1 Function to get membership type*/
void getMembershipType (int membershipYears, int *memberShipType){
    
                if (membershipYears <=5) {
                *memberShipType = 1;
                } else if (membershipYears >5 && membershipYears<=10)
                {
                    *memberShipType = 2;
                } else
                { 
                    *memberShipType = 3;
                }
                
}

/*2.2 Action - reading a supporter */

void readSupporter (tSupporter *aficionado) {
            /*Read name*/
                printf("NAME (25 CHAR MAX, NO SPACES)?\n");
                scanf("%s", aficionado->name);
            /*Read age*/
                printf("AGE (AN INTEGER)?\n");
                scanf("%d", &aficionado->age);
            /*Read years as member*/
                printf("MEMBERSHIP YEARS (AN INTEGER)?\n");
                scanf("%d", &aficionado->membershipYears);
            /*Records*/
                printf("HAS RECORDS (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE)?\n");
                scanf("%d", &aficionado->hasRecords);
                }
                
/*2.3 Action - Show the data of a given user, retorning all the fields of struct*/
void writeSupporter(tSupporter users, int memberShipType) {
    printf("NAME: %s\n", users.name);
    printf("AGE: %d\n", users.age);
    printf("MEMBERSHIP YEARS: %d\n", users.membershipYears);
    printf("HAS RECORDS (0-FALSE, 1-TRUE): %d\n", users.hasRecords);
    printf("MEMBERSHIP TYPE (1-BASE, 2-SILVER, 3-GOLD): %d\n", memberShipType);
}


/*2.4 Function - Calculate points of a supporter tSupporter*/

void getPoints (tSupporter aficionado, int memberShipType, int hasRecords, int *totalPointsSupporter, int i){

    int totalPointsAux =0;
    
    if (memberShipType == 1) {
        totalPointsAux = 10;
    } else if (memberShipType == 2){
        totalPointsAux = 15;
    } else if (memberShipType == 3){
        totalPointsAux = 20;
    }
    
    if (hasRecords == 0) {
        totalPointsAux = totalPointsAux+0;
    } else if (hasRecords == 1) {
        totalPointsAux = totalPointsAux-5;
    }
    
    totalPointsSupporter[i] = totalPointsAux;
    
}

/* AUX FUNCTION: SUPPORTER COPY*/

void supporterCpy (tSupporter users[], tSupporter aficionado, int i){

    strcpy(users[i].name, aficionado.name);
    users[i].age = aficionado.age;
    users[i].membershipYears = aficionado.membershipYears;
    users[i].hasRecords = aficionado.hasRecords;
    }
```

When I input some data I get:

```
Name: +V
Age: -208988632
Years: 32676
Records 0 (this one is correct)
Type: 9
Points: 15 (this one is correct)
```

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

output should be:

```
Name: NAME / STRING
Age: int (in the above example was 25 years)
Years: 8 (the input number readed by the function). 
Records 0 (this one is correct)
Type: 9   (0, 1, or 2 as options)
Points: 15 (this one is correct)
```

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions carefully. Don't tag with C++ the C code.

Comment: Please don’t spam the C++ tag, no C++ is discussed in this question. Using the right tags saves readers’ time and focuses their attention where it’s needed.

Comment: Pick one weird behaviour. Isolate it (use [mre] for inspiration). Unless the problem deals with getting input from the user remove all of the user input code and replace it with one set of input that produces exactly the unwanted behaviour you're asking about, Clearly describe both your expectations and the observed results, including what you observe when stepping through the program with a debugger. When you simply dump a bunch of code and they effectively state, "There's a bug in there, somewhere" you instantly lose most of the folk who would otherwise help you.

Comment: Also turn on ALL of the diagnostics you have available. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/1cndr3cfv Here the warnings aren't all that useful, but the sanitizer picks off a couple of nasties that you should look at more closely.

Comment: W.r.t. the question: Run it under `valgrind`. It will tell you where exactly your invalid memory access happens. And my guess is that it will point at this bug: `writeSupporter(users[aTheWinnerIs], users[aTheWinnerIsIndex].membershipYears);` Which should have been: `writeSupporter(users[aTheWinnerIsIndex], users[aTheWinnerIsIndex].membershipYears);` In any case: (1) Please learn to isolate a MRE. Most of your code snippet is irrelevant to the question. (2) Please format the code properly. It is virtually impossible to read. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: You don't check that the `scanf()` function worked each time you use it.  But if it fails, your program is going to be unhappy.  Always check that input functions succeed.  Always check that you successfully open any files you try to open, too.

Answer (score 1):

The error can be detected on the line it happens using GCC's address sanitizer: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5Wq9Kq936)

This identifies the last line of `getPoints`, which is saying you're overflowing an array with the following:

```
totalPointsSupporter[i] = totalPointsAux;
```

Why would that be? You know that `i` is in range, and that the `totalPointsSupporter` array declared in `main` is sized correctly. So it *must* be the pointer.

Indeed, if you look up the call stack to where you invoke the function, the critical error becomes evident:

```
getPoints(aficionado, memberShipType, aficionado.hasRecords, &totalPointsSupporter[i], i);
```

Here, you're double-indexing. Your `getPoints` function expects a pointer to the beginning of the array so that it can address with `i`. But you are passing a pointer to the actual element. That means indices 0, 1, and 2 will effectively address indices 0, 2, and 4. That last one is way off the end of the array.

The quick fix is this:

```
getPoints(aficionado, memberShipType, aficionado.hasRecords, totalPointsSupporter, i);
```

The more involved fix is to ask yourself *why* you need to provide `i` to this function at all. It is a bit of an anti-pattern. Why not provide the actual pointer to the element instead of encoding its array storage into the function?

You're also doing that in your `supporterCpy` function, which is even weirder because you could have passed a pointer also. You're even passing the struct as a copy. And the function was barely necessary to begin with because in `main` you can just do:

```
users[i] = aficionado;
```